# Me llega un json en una callback y quiero obtener el valor de una propiedad

Tags: nodejs

Que tal tengo el siguiente código:

```
function login(req, res){
    req.getConnection((err, conexion)=>{
    if(err) return next(err);
    conexion.query('select * from tabla where id=?', req.body.id, (err, dato)=>{
      res.status(200).send({  campos: dato });
    });
  });
}
```

el json dato me arroja lo siguiente:

```
{
    "campos": [
        {
            "id": 12,
            "campo1": "rulo",
            "campo2": "a$10$gIoFFPgXcDoJ07CN1qq",
            "campo2": "administrador"
        }
    ]
}
```

y quiero tomar el valor del campo2.

ya intente con un for y foreach, pero no logro accesar a este dato...

gracias de antemano.

Comment: No se puede. Ese JSON no es válido.

Answer (score 3):

No se puede, al menos no tal y como lo tienes definido.

El [JSON compartido no es válido](https://jsonlint.com/?json=%7B%22campos%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A12%2C%22campo1%22%3A%22rulo%22%2C%22campo2%22%3A%22a%2410%24gIoFFPgXcDoJ07CN1qq%22%2C%22campo2%22%3A%22administrador%22%7D%5D%7D) porque no puede haber claves duplicadas (al igual que un objeto no puede tener dos propiedades con el mismo nombre). Al encontrarse una clave duplicada, el navegador intentará solucionar el problema, quedándose con el último valor:

```js
var datos = {
    "campos": [
        {
            "id": 12,
            "campo1": "rulo",
            "campo2": "a$10$gIoFFPgXcDoJ07CN1qq",
            "campo2": "administrador"
        }
    ]
};

console.log(datos);
```

Si tienes una clave/propiedad que tiene más de un valor, deberás ponerla como un array de valores en lugar de duplicar llaves, algo como esto:

```js
var datos = {
    "campos": [
        {
            "id": 12,
            "campo1": "rulo",
            "campo2": [
                       "a$10$gIoFFPgXcDoJ07CN1qq",
                       "administrador"
                      ]
        }
    ]
};

console.log(datos);
```

Ese [JSON ya es válido](https://jsonlint.com/?json=%7B%22campos%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A12%2C%22campo1%22%3A%22rulo%22%2C%22campo2%22%3A%5B%22a%2410%24gIoFFPgXcDoJ07CN1qq%22%2C%22administrador%22%5D%7D%5D%7D) y entonces podrás acceder al `campo2` como se accede a cualquier array: `campo2[0]` devolverá "a$10$gIoFFPgXcDoJ07CN1qq" y `campo2[1]` devolverá "administrador".

Comment: Excelente respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Como te dijeron arriba, en primer instancia esta mal definido el JSON para el propósito de usarlo con javascript, así que si tienes acceso a la api del cliente que envia los datos, te sugiriría cambiar eso.

De ser imposible, hay una alternativa.
Los valores se acopla en el momento que la cadena llega al servidor y se convierte en objeto. Esto lo hace automáticamente ya que al parecer usas el framework express.

La solución sería no usar express, sino usar la clase nata de node.js http.Server, capturar el body mediante los eventos "data" y "end" y parsear el texto obtenido con la función JSON.parse(text, reviver).

El argumento reviver es una función que te permitirá analizar cada una de las variables cuando se convierten en objeto.
Echa un vistazo:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse